Auth Code flow with PKCE with API Based Integration (without Keycloak redirect Url
I am looking for approach where we create do Auth code flow with PKCE grant type in Keycloak and invoke the flow with Just API based approach instead of using Keycloak UI using redirect url.
This will be integrated with flutter Mobile applicatio

You can do something like this to acquire accessToken and refreshToken just by using API call:
abstract class OAuthSource {
  Future<Either<Failure, TokenResponse>> login({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  });
  Future<Either<Failure, TokenResponse>> refreshToken({
    required String refreshToken,
  });
}

class OAuthSourceImpl implements OAuthSource {
  final String _authority;
  final String _clientId;
  final String _clientSecret;

  OAuthSourceImpl({
    required String authority,
    required String clientId,
    required String clientSecret,
  })  : _authority = authority,
        _clientId = clientId,
        _clientSecret = clientSecret;

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, TokenResponse>> login({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      final authorizationEndpoint =
          Uri.parse('${_authority}/protocol/openid-connect/token');

      var body = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'client_id': _clientId,
        'client_secret': _clientSecret,
        'username': email,
        'password': password,
      };

      var response = await http.post(
        authorizationEndpoint,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: body,
      );
      return response.parse(decoder: TokenResponse.fromJson);
    } catch (e) {
      return Left(Failure.server(message: e.toString(), code: 500));
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, TokenResponse>> refreshToken({
    required String refreshToken,
  }) async {
    try {
      final refreshTokenEndpoint =
          Uri.parse('${_authority}/protocol/openid-connect/token');

      var body = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'client_id': _clientId,
        'client_secret': _clientSecret,
        'refresh_token': refreshToken,
      };

      var response = await http.post(
        refreshTokenEndpoint,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: body,
      );

      return response.parse(decoder: TokenResponse.fromJson);
    } catch (e) {
      return Left(Failure.server(message: e.toString(), code: 500));
    }
  }
}

Here, _authority is your Keycloak realm URL. Also, you need to create a confidential client and pass the credentials in _clientID and _clientSecret.
I don't think you can use PKCE without being redirected to the Keycloak login page.
